# IEnumerable<string> to string

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this:

```
string test = "";
somestring.ToList().Take(50).Select(
    delegate(char x)
    {
        test += x;
        return x;
    }
);
```

Why is `test` empty after that? I don't care about the return of that actually (I know its `IEnumerable<string>`).

If this is all seems a mess then how can I convert the `IEnumerable<char>`
returned by `Select()` to `string` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because you didn't execute the query. Linq is lazy. It will be executed when you do either `foreach` or `ToList`/`ToArray`/`ToDictionary`.

and i advice to do it like that

```
string test = new string(somestring.Take(50).ToArray());
```

or even using

```
string test = somestring.Substring(0, 50);
```

More on that. `Select` is intended to apply some kind of transformation to every element in sequence. This operation is also known as `map`. If you want to produce single element from sequence it is [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx), aka `reduce`. It is not lazy, it forces execution of query.

Comment: `Remove`? I think you mean `Substring`?

Comment: @Greg Linq is declarative framework. this is sometimes surprising stuff for imperative-minded developers.

Comment: This will not compile if `somestring` is of type `IEnumberable<string>`. The string class does not have an overloaded constructor that takes a string array.

Comment: @0xA3 you are right and wrong. It will compile, because i pass `char[]` not `string[]`. in second case it won't compile

Comment: @0xA3 somestring is `string`, thus `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course. When I wrote my comment, the question asked about `IEnumerable<string>`, hence I assumed `somestring` is of that type.

Comment: @Andrey: Yep, downright confusing I'd say. "Sometimes when you do things with LINQ, they don't do anything at all".

Answer (score 16):

(Others have explained why it doesn't work.)

Your question doesn't quite make sense at the moment - it's not clear whether you're *actually* dealing with an `IEnumerable<char>` or an `IEnumerable<string>`. (Your text suggests `IEnumerable<string>`; your code suggests `IEnumerable<char>`). If it's an `IEnumerable<string>` and you're using .NET 4, it's really easy:

```
string combined = string.Join("", list.Take(50));
```

If you're using .NET 3.5, it's still pretty easy:

```
string combined = string.Join("", list.Take(50).ToArray());
```

Obviously use something like "," if you want a delimiter between the strings.

If you're dealing with a general `IEnumerable<char>` then use

```
string combined = new string(chars.Take(50).ToArray());
```

If you're *actually* dealing with a string to start with, use `Substring` :)

Comment: he iterates over string, see `delegate(char x)`. I don't think that it is efficient to do string.Join over ienumerable of chars.

Comment: @Andrey: I was basing the answer on the claim that he's trying to concatenate an `IEnumerable<string>`, not an `IEnumerable<char>`... basically the question's broken at the moment. I've edited to indicate that.

Comment: yeah i meant ienumrable<char> not string that was a typo sorry

Comment: "" over string.Empty? Go iron your hands :P

Comment: @Stacker: Okay, that changes things - use the bottom approach (which Timwi had also suggested).

Comment: @annakata: I've explained elsewhere why I prefer "" over `string.Empty` - I find it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable<char>` but you aren't enumerating it in your code so the delegate won't be executed. If you change it to:

```
string test = "";
somestring.Take(50).Select(
    delegate(char x)
    {
        test += x;
        return x;
    }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you only declared the sequence, but you never executed it. If you added another `.ToList()` at the end, then `test` would have the characters in it.

However, I strongly recommend against this practice. You are using the evaluation of a sequence to *cause side-effects*. You have already discovered that the results are confusing. If you really just want the first 50 items of a sequence, just use `Take` alone:

```
var partSequence = fullSequence.Take(50);
```

Your above example could be written something like this:

```
var partString = new string(someString.Take(50).ToArray());
```

but I’m sure you’re aware of [`string.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Select` is lazy, so the function you pass in will only be evaluated once you use the result of Select.

Generally it's bad idea to use functions with side effects with Select. You should probably use foreach instead.

In this particular case, you can just use the String.Join method.